# How do I use a github based laravel project?

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4

New to laravel, and web development in general, so pardon if this sounds like a stupid question.

I'm trying to setup a basic laravel framework that has authentication. I came across this: https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel which on the face of it, it seems to be the right sort of thing that I'm looking for.

There's a few things that I don't understand.

1. **Sentinel: Sentry Implementation for Laravel 4**   -   This package is based on my L4withSentry demo repo.
2. **Laravel 4 with Sentry 2 - Version 2.0** - This is a demo of Sentry    2 integrated with Laravel 4 and Bootstrap 3.0. This repo  is intended    to be for reference only - if you want to use this
   code in your own    app I suggest using Sentinel - a Laravel package
   based on this repo.

I'm expecting that I should be able to clone the project (item 1 above), and then make a few configuration adjustments and have the basic example up and running.

The part that confuses me is that they seem to be two very different sets of files. For example - the L4withSentry example has a "home.blade.php" in a recognisable Laravel style layout. The "laravel with sentry" (item 2 above) doesn't even have an app directory.

Am I supposed to clone and merge both of them?

I'd be grateful for a few pointers, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting in Laravel, don't try to make things too easy for you just yet. The best you can do, at least in the very beginning, is to install a Laravel and start doing things your way. You can then install Sentry and do your authentication with it, using your own line of development.

About those two packages: both are packages which use `"cartalyst/sentry"` to provide authentication via routes, controllers, views and models. Basically you can install it in any Laravel app and have those things done for you. To use them you need first to create a Laravel app and then install one of those packages, here's an example on installing them using Composer:

```
composer require "rydurham/sentinel":"1.*"    (this is an example for one of them)
```

Then you have to configure the package, as the readme, to make it work for you.

Those are not applications you can install and work with. There are some other Laravel application bootstrapppers around, but I would not use them, because, as I said, if you are starting, you better understand the concepts of Laravel, or you will end up being lost in something you don't know if it's Laravel or not.

Comment: The Composer installation and subsequent configuration is easy. But I hear you, and it's good advice. I was just approaching it from a point of trying to get the basic app running and then "looking under the hood"

Comment: The problem with a "basic app" is that, really fast, you see things the other guy is doing different from what you would normally do and then you get stuck with some hard to modify structure and start to create workarounds even before creating your app. Laravel makes it very easy to create those things, that's why I prefer to do it myself.